# Can't seem to find a way to loop through a PL/SQL array?

Tags: sql, database, plsql

I am trying to do this:

```
arrCauses := APEX_UTIL.STRING_TO_TABLE(:P1_CAUSE);
FOR c IN 1..arrCauses.count LOOP
  INSERT INTO DT_EVENT_CAUSE (
  EVENT_ID,
  CAUSE_ID)

  VALUES (
  nextPK, c);
END LOOP;
```

or this

```
arrCauses := APEX_UTIL.STRING_TO_TABLE(:P1_CAUSE);
FOR c IN arrCauses.first..arrCauses.last LOOP
  INSERT INTO DT_EVENT_CAUSE (
  EVENT_ID,
  CAUSE_ID)

  VALUES (
  nextPK, c);
END LOOP;
```

Problem is...c is always just the count, so if the array is 1 item, a c of 1 will be inserted. If the array if 3 items, c's of 1, 2 and 3 will be inserted. As opposed to actual values from the array. What am I doing wrong?!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the index to retrieve the value within your array:

```
 VALUES (
 nextPK, arrCauses(c));
```

instead of

```
 VALUES (
 nextPK, c);
```

;)